# WeakReference in C# - How did action instance got lost?

Tags: c#

I am trying things out with weak references in vs2015 and here is an example where I dont understand why is the weak reference of the action instance I created in the end completely lost?

Could you guys help me with this issue.

Here is the code and Invoke method aint invoking since the action has at that point null value. But it shouldnt have null value.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class2 c1 = new Class2();
        Class4 c4 = new Class4();
        Class3 c3 = new Class3();
        c4.AssignActionA(c3, c4.CreateAction(c1));
        c4.AssignActionB(c3, c4.CreateAction(c1));
        GC.Collect();

        Class5 c5 = new Class5();
        c5.CallActionA(c3);
        c5.CallActionB(c3);

        //Task.Run(() =>
        //{
        //    Class5 c5 = new Class5();
        //    c5.CallAction(c3);      
        //});

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Class5
{
    public void CallActionA(Class3 c3)
    {
        Action a;
        c3.A.TryGetTarget(out a);
        a?.Invoke();
    }

    public void CallActionB(Class3 c3)
    {
        c3.B();
    }
}

public class Class4
{
    public Action CreateAction(Class2 c1)
    {
        //Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        Action a = () =>
        {
            var temp = c1;
        };

        return a;
    }

    public void AssignActionA(Class3 c3, Action a)
    {
        c3.A = new WeakReference<Action>(a);
    }

    public void AssignActionB(Class3 c3, Action b)
    {
        c3.B = b;
    }
}

public class Class2
{
}

public class Class3
{
    public WeakReference<Action> A { get; set; }
    public Action B { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would have expected that... your only reference to the object is a weak reference and you call gc collect.  The MSDN states "Represents a weak reference, which references an object while still allowing that object to be reclaimed by garbage collection".  You still need a reference to protect it from collection. I believe the intent of this is to allow transient object hold references to shared resources.

Comment: Your code example should be minimalist and only include code pertinent to the question.

Comment: I changed my code please take a look and tell me why does action get lost?

Comment: for action A it is still the same effect.  your 2 actions are not the same instance.  try on your assignActionA to set it in c3.a and c3.b.... then it should live.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GC uses roots to start the *mark* phase of Garbage Collection. In your sample code the only roots that matter are local variables of method which is being executed when the collection starts. There are no other static fields or anything like that. And from there that `WeakReference` is the only way the `Action` can be reached. Because of that is eligible for collection (that's the entire point of `WeakReference`):

> Represents a weak reference, which references an object while still allowing that object to be reclaimed by garbage collection.

When you force garbage collection it is reclaimed and you can't call I anymore.

Comment: I changed my code. Please take a look and tell me what am I missing here with weak references. thx